# Python XML, how to access ancestor tag?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

XML be like:

```
    <Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food" ItemID="101">
        <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Fruit">
            <Section SectionLevel="3" SectionID="From a tree">
                <Content>Apple</Content>
            </Section>
        </Section>
    </Section>
    
    <Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food" ItemID="103">
        <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Meat">
            <Section SectionLevel="3" SectionID="From a cow">
                <Content>Beef</Content>
            </Section>
        </Section>
    </Section>
```

Objective is to find the item that is food, fruit and from a tree. Then print the content and the ItemID. How to access ItemID when I am in the content level?

```
for element in tree.findall(".//Section[@SectionID='Food']/Section[@SectionID='Fruit']/Section[@SectionID='From a tree']/Content"):
    print(element.text)
    print(content.find("./ancestor::Section").attrib['ItemID'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xpath selecting ancestors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208236/xpath-selecting-ancestors)

Comment: @JaSON It might tell me what the xpath is but it do not tell me how to utilized it in python element tree.

Comment: To use the `ancestor` axis, you need to use lxml and the `xpath` method. `find` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

So I've tested with:

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree
```

This lxml code:

```
f = StringIO('''\
<root>
 <Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food" ItemID="101">
    <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Fruit">
        <Section SectionLevel="3" SectionID="From a tree">
            <Content>Apple</Content>
        </Section>
    </Section>
 </Section>
 <Section SectionLevel="1" SectionID="Food" ItemID="103">
    <Section SectionLevel="2" SectionID="Meat">
        <Section SectionLevel="3" SectionID="From a cow">
            <Content>Beef</Content>
        </Section>
    </Section>
 </Section>
</root>
''')

tree = etree.parse(f)
```

Then use this for loop:

```
for i in tree.xpath(".//Section[@SectionID='Food']/Section[@SectionID='Fruit']/Section[@SectionID='From a tree']/Content"):
  content = i.text
  print(content)
  itemid = i.xpath('.//ancestor::Section')[0].get('ItemID')
  print(itemid)
```

Result:

```
Apple
101
```